# Matching a field with rowgroup value

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm converting some reports from Access to Oracle. Within Access you can use multiple headers but within SSRS you cannot.

I need to place (within the header of SSRS) a field which takes its value from the value of the current row group.

I know it's unnecessary however, those are the requirements I have been given within the spec.

Any idea how I would achieve this?

[image: Visual Explanation of Requirements]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, you can do something similar in SSRS. Some similar data to yours:

[image]

And a table based on this:

[image]

There is a group based on `DepartmentName`. This is set to page break for each group member.

Note that I have **three** group header rows: one to display the Department Name at the top of the page, one for the columns headers and one for spacing.

Since this is in the Group scope, it will always display the correct name:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah beautiful, thank you Ian. I completely forgot about grouping it and placing it within the tablix. It was approaching 5PM and it seems as if my mind had melted. 

Again, thank you Ian. I'll implement that tomorrow!